# Mann-Kendall trend test minimum lenght of the time-series

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, trend

What is the minimum length of a time-series for considering the results of the Mann-Kendall trend test "coherent"?

Comment: What do you mean by "coherent"?

Comment: After I posted this, I found that in order to consider Z following a normal distribution the length of the time series should be over 10

Comment: 1. How does the quality of that approximation relate to "coherence" (whatever coherence mean)? 2. The R package doesn't use the normal approximation for Kendall's tau until n exceeds 50. The approximation is a bit rough at n=10, Personally I would avoid using it until n was a bit nearer 20.

Answer (score 1):

The Mann-Kendall function in R requires at least 3 data points. Look here: [Mann-Kendall test in R using 'Kendall' package: exact test or approximation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196878/mann-kendall-test-in-r-using-kendall-package-exact-test-or-approximation/196942?noredirect=1#comment373817_196942)

Comment: I am not sure this answers the question asked, since that concerned whether the results could be defined as "coherent", not just whether the calculation could be performed. But sadly the intended meaning of "coherent" was not well-explained.